# Error when trying to deploy to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, class

I am getting the following error, when trying to deploy to Google App Engine, an app that is working successfully on localhost. I am using JRE6. What am I doing wrong?

```
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 
'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg8577401854428955678.tmp'
   java.lang.RuntimeException: The application contains Java 7 classes, 
     but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.

Debugging information may be found in 
    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy2750980602587848015.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message provides the solution:

> "The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set."

You can add additional arguments in the "Run/Debug" settings in Eclipse. You'll see a tab called "Arguments", and it will already contain some flags like --port=8088 or --address=127.0.0.1 or something like that.

[image: Run/Debug Settings in Eclipse]

If you add in that flag, the warnings should go away.

Alternatively, get rid of the Java 7 classes and replace them with Java 6 classes, especially if adding the flag doesn't help. You mention in your question that the app is configured to run using Java 6. If you're using Java 7 where it's expecting 6, that can create problems for the compiler.